# HTML5 Canvas loaded using a onclick event

Tags: android, jquery, html, canvas, touch

How would I go about adding a html5 canvas element on a click function or does it need to be on document ready or load?

What I would like to do is create a way to use the canvas to act as a highlighter, the user clicks the hightlighter button, then draws the highlighted mark.

I was thinking of including this on a click event so I could continue to use my touchwipe events.  THis is on an Android device, I currently have a slider cycling through rasterized pages of a book that I want to allow users to markup.  The canvas element would sit on top of the img's and be semi transparent.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

canvas element behaves like other dom elements in this case. Try:

```
var x = $('<canvas height="100px" width="100px"> </canvas> '),
    y = x[0].getContext('2d');

y.strokeRect(0,0,50,50)

x.appendTo('body')
```